# How to convert geospatial coordinates dataFrame to native x,y projection?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, coordinates, geospatial

I have a following dataframe, the lat and lon are the latitudes and longitudes in Geographic coordinates system. I am trying to convert these coordinate system into native (x, y) projection.

I have tried pyproj for single points, but how do I proceed for the whole dataframe with thousands of rows.

```
       time                 lat        lon 
     0 2011-01-31 02:41:00  18.504273  -66.009332
     1 2011-01-31 02:42:00  18.504673  -66.006225
```

I am trying to get something like this:

```
       time                 lat        lon        x_Projn    y_Projn
     0 2011-01-31 02:41:00  18.504273  -66.009332 resp_x_val resp_y_val
     1 2011-01-31 02:42:00  18.504673  -66.006225 resp_x_val resp_y_val
     and so on...
```

Following is the code I tried for lat/lon to x,y system:

```
      from pyproj import Proj, transform

      inProj = Proj(init='epsg:4326')
      outProj = Proj(init='epsg:3857')
      x1,y1 = -105.150271116, 39.7278572773
      x2,y2 = transform(inProj,outProj,x1,y1)
      print (x2,y2)
```

Output:

```
      -11705274.637407782 4826473.692203013
```

Thanks for any kind of help.

Comment: And the code with your attempt is where?

Comment: What's wrong with the output?

Comment: @Marat Nothing wrong with above output, but thats only for one single point, i want to do it for whole dataFrame. Also I dont want to use geopandas  because it has compatibility issues with fiona which I am using. Is there a way to do for the whole df at once with pyproj ?

Comment: @Marat It works, but I am getting "Object" dtype and not a df, when I am converting it into a df, both x,y coordinates are in the same column, how can I put them in separate column? I am sorry , I am new to python. Also, I would request you to post that geopandas and Shapely solution as well, I will try that in a separate environment. Thanks.

Comment: @Marat Thank you so much, its perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `pyproj` only converts point by point. I guess something like this should work:

```
import pandas as pd
from pyproj import Proj, transform

inProj = Proj(init='epsg:4326')
outProj = Proj(init='epsg:3857')

def towgs84(row):
    return pd.Series(transform(inProj, outProj, row["lat"], row["lon"]))

wsg84_df = df.apply(towgs84, axis=1)  # new coord dataframe with two columns
```

Comment: Using pyproj v. 3.5.0, I get a deprecation warning: "FutureWarning: '+init=<authority>:<code>' syntax is deprecated. '<authority>:<code>' is the preferred initialization method. When making the change, be mindful 
of axis order changes: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/gotchas.html#axis-order-changes-in-proj-6"

Consider using the approach described here: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/gotchas.html#upgrading-to-pyproj-2-from-pyproj-1

Comment: This worked for me. That said, the process seems to be extremely slow.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the rows in a pandas data frame, transform the Longitude and Latitude values for each row, make two lists with the 1st and second coordinate values, and then turn the lists into new columns in original your data frame. Maybe not the prettiest, but this got the job done for me.

```
from pyproj import Proj, transform

M1s = [] #initiate empty list for 1st coordinate value
M2s = [] #initiate empty list for 2nd coordinate value

for index, row in df.iterrows(): #iterate over rows in the dataframe
    long = row["Longitude (decimal degrees)"] #get the longitude for one row
    lat = row["Latitude (decimal degrees)"] #get the latitude for one row
    M1 = (transform(Proj(init='epsg:4326'), Proj(init='epsg:3857'), long, lat))[0] #get the 1st coordinate
    M2 = (transform(Proj(init='epsg:4326'), Proj(init='epsg:3857'), long, lat))[1] #get the second coordinate
    M1s.append(M1) #append 1st coordinate to list
    M2s.append(M2) #append second coordinate to list

df['M1'] = M1s #new dataframe column with 1st coordinate
df['M2'] = M2s #new dataframe columne with second coordinate
```